# ¿A que se debe este mensaje/error en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo este mensaje en la ventana "Event Log", esto solo al iniciar Android Studio, mis programas corren correctamente y ya no vuelve a aparecer este mensaje, solo que antes de esto tuve problemas con el emulador por lo cual mis programas no se ejecutaban, después de hacer varias cosas pude correrlos más sin embargo este mensaje siempre me aparece al inicio, ya intente reiniciar el emulador desde comandos adb y limpiar datos del mismo desde "Device Manager" pero sigue apareciendo, tal ves en el proceso de querer arreglar mi problema anterior hice algo que ocasiono esto (soy novato en este IDE)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> - daemon not running starting now at tcp:5037
> - daemon started successfully

Comment: No es problema, es un proceso esencial y siempre se inicializa al iniciar Android Studio. Probablemente los problemas con el emulador eran porque este proceso no iniciaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los mensajes:

> - daemon not running starting now at tcp:5037
> - daemon started successfully

no son ningún problema o error.

"Daemon" es un proceso que se ejecuta de forma continua en segundo plano (background), este proceso es esencial en Android Studio y al ser continuo siempre está listo para usarse. Los mensajes indican la inicialización del proceso "daemon" para Android Studio y como comentas aparece al iniciar la IDE.

Por lo tanto, el problema sería si este proceso no pudiera ejecutarse, ejemplo:

[image: jorgesys daemon android]

en este caso el problema generalmente se debe a que se requiere más memoria, en este caso se aumenta la cantidad de memoria definida en `gradle.properties`, aunque actualmente el valor predeterminado es `-Xmx1024m`, lo cual es suficiente:

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```